# Export list of data frames to CSVs in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I've got a list of data frames I'm trying to preform a function on and export the results. The function spits out a result, and I then want to turn the results into a data frame and export to a .CSV. Here's what I currently have:

```
for df, filename in zip(df_list, filename_list):
    function(df)
    results_df = pd.DataFrame(function_results)
    results_df.to_csv(filename)
```

The error occurs when I try to export the .csv. If I just run the loop with the function and print results to the console like so:

```
for df in df_list:
    function(df)
```

It works fine. When I try to loop the .csv export though I get

> Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'close'

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need `function_results = function(df)` ?

Comment: @jezrael no the object is created in the function

Comment: Can you check type(filename)? It looks like 'filename' is a list for some reason, and therefore when it tries to close the file, it fails.

Comment: @Alex maybe I’m doing it incorrectly but filename is supposed to be an element from filename_list in the same way df is an element from df_list. Filename_list is a list of strings I’m trying to assign to the csv files

Comment: @Oct I know what you're trying to do, but it doesn't seem to be interpreting filename as a string, can you get it to print(type(filename)) and tell me what it is?

Comment: @Alex Christ I'm an idiot and you clued me into it so thanks! I was calling 


    results_df.to_csv(filename_list)

Comment: @Oct, haha, don't worry about it. I've done the same thing enough times!